# Setup zend skeleton application

Tags: apache, zend-framework

I am trying to setup the zend skeleton application in my Windows 10 machine. However, since port 80 was not available, I am trying to configure on port 8080. But every time I do not get the zend skeleton page. I only get the apache page that says "It works". Pls suggest what I am doing wrong.

In apache httpd.conf, I made below changes:

```
Listen 8080
ServerName localhost:8080
```

In httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName zendskeleton.localhost
    DocumentRoot C:/zendskeleton/public
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory C:/zendskeleton/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In Windows hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1              zendskeleton.localhost localhost
```

Comment: Is the module "rewrite_module" green checked when you click on Wamp icon (in tray icons) -> Apache -> Apache Modules ? and do you have rules in .htaccess wich use it.

Comment: Whatever is taking port 80 shouldn't be.